# Accessing AssemblyVersion number from assembly information to use in the post build event command line

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to get access to the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion numbers in the assembly information using the post build event command line in visual studio 2008.  Is there a way to get access to that information similar to how $(TargetName) gets its macro definition from the project title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are declared in the AssemblyInfo.cs file and embedded in the $(TargetPath).  You could write a little utility to dig it out again.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length == 0) throw new Exception("Assembly path required");
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(asm.GetName().Version.ToString());
        var vers = (AssemblyFileVersionAttribute)asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false)[0];
        Console.WriteLine(vers.Version);
    }
}
```

Post build event ought to look something like this:

```
c:\bin\myutil.exe $(TargetPath)
```

Comment: Thanks, the `Assembly.LoadFile` is exactly what I need.